# Get data from one ViewModel to UI State Data class with another ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have one MainViewModel where I get the userData from firestore (with use case and repository) depending on the AuthState and the currentUser uid. I have userData with a StateFlow. I use this viewmodel (not shared) in all my screens to update the UI depending on this flow.
I have one Profile Screen (to Edit profile) with EditProfileViewModel and EditProfileUIState.

The question is that I need this userData from MainViewModel in my EditProfileUIState so I can update the values and when the user clicks in Save, EditProfileViewModel will take the userData from EditProfileUIState and Update it in Firestore. Now I'm getting this flow in the Profile Screen composable and with a LaunchEffect I execute an event to pass the data to the viewmodel and update the UI State Data class. But I don't know if this is a good approach..

Which is the best way to do this in Clean Architecture (MVVM)? Maybe another way with use cases? I don't want to resolve the response in each viewmodel I need to get the userData..

I have the following code:

MainViewModel.kt

```
private val _userData = MutableStateFlow<UserData?>(null)
val userData: StateFlow<UserData?> = _userData

init {
    getAuthState()
}

private fun getAuthState(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        authUseCases.getAuthState(viewModelScope).collectLatest {
            when(it){
                true -> {
                    _userData.update { null }
                }
                false -> {
                    authUseCases.currentUser()?.uid?.let { userId ->
                        getUserData(userId)
                    } ?: Log.d("PROVES","CAN'T GET USER")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getUserData(userId: String){
    Log.d("PROVES","GetUserData")
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userUseCases.getUserData(userId)
            .collectLatest { response ->
            when(response) {
                is Success -> {
                    _userData.update { response.data }
                    Log.d("PROVES","${response.data}")
                }
                is Failure -> {
                    Log.d("PROVES","GET DATA FAILURE RESPONSE")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileEditUIState.kt

```
data class ProfileEditUIState (val isLoading: Boolean = false, val userData: UserData? = null)
```

ProfileEditViewModel.kt

```
private val _profileEditUiState = MutableStateFlow(ProfileEditUIState())
val profileEditUiState: StateFlow<ProfileEditUIState> = _profileEditUiState.asStateFlow()

fun onEvent(event: ProfileEditUIEvent) {
    when(event) {
        is ProfileEditUIEvent.UserDataLoaded -> {
            _profileEditUiState.update {
                it.copy(userData = event.userData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Screen Composable:

```
fun ProfileEditContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    profileEditViewModel: ProfileEditViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    onSignInClick: () -> Unit,
) {

    val state by profileEditViewModel.profileEditUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val userData by mainViewModel.userData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    userData?.let {
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            profileEditViewModel.onEvent(ProfileEditUIEvent.UserDataLoaded(it))
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would use use case to fetch data in `ProfileEditViewModel` make it a `sharedFlow` so both could collect simultaneously

**ProfileEditViewModel.kt**

```
val profileEditUiState: StateFlow<ProfileEditUIState> = 
    userUseCases.getUserData(userId)
         .map{ ProfileEditUiState(false, data = it) }
         .stateIn(...)
```

Comment: But I only need a copy of this UserData in the profileEditUiState, the one from MainViewModel is the data that I use in all my app.